# Presenting selling statistics for multiple tags per each sold item in mobile application

Tags: android, statistics

I am writing application mobile (React native) application that lists items that users buy and sell. Each item can be tagged with some tags. I want to present some statistics statistics like:

- profit per each tag,
- items sold per each tag,
- etc.

so user can see what are me most popular things user sells, but don't know how to do it properly due to this multiple tags to each item relation.

**What are possible ways of presenting tag statistics on mobile application?**

Comment: Do you want to show these statistics on tags that are listed on the item or on the list of tags if there is one?

Comment: What kind of design language already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps build a dashboard inside the app where you can rank each tag and get detailed statistics.

Comment: There's not a lot of details here. Are you able to expand on your suggestion? How would this solve OP's problem? Are you suggesting to show the relationships or correlations between co-occurring tags at all? If so, how?